# Why do I not have to pass an instance of Label to my route helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller

For route helpers like `edit_admin_label_template_path(@label, @template)`, it requires two instances to create the route, otherwise raising a RoutingError exception.

But for the route `new_admin_label_template_path`, it doesn't need an instance of Label. The current_page url on the page I am using this route for is  `http://localhost:3000/admin/labels/5/templates`, so I am assuming it is pulling from the `params[:label_id]`, but I don't get how exactly. Also, why does it not do this on the other page where I have to pass both an instance of Label AND Template?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the route pulling in the label_id from the params, it does so from the URL. It matches against something that looks something like:

`/admin/labels/:label_id/templates`

where `:label_id` can be anything

When you are creating a new template, you only need to know the id of the label because the template id is not yet set. When you edit the template, the id for template is set, and you need to supply both that and the id of the label to the rails router. Note that this is dependent upon how you set up your nested routes. For more information on routing, you should check out the [Rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: But why doesn't it know to pull in `:label_id` for the edit route helper?

Comment: This is all dependent upon how you set up nesting for your routes. It doesn't need the label_id to find the template, since template_id is unique, but you have your routes set up in a way that requires you to send both

Answer (score 0):

When you say "edit" it needs to now which template? and which label's template?
this is the reason rails need both @label and @template.

But when you say "new" it doesn't need to now which template because template is the one that will be creating. just @label is fine.

btw you should take a look at [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and should listen:

> Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.
>
> Deeply-nested resources quickly become cumbersome

Comment: I understand that with new, there is no template yet, but the newhelper doesn't even required a label to be passed in, why does it need to be passed in for the edit route?

Comment: because if you just pass @template as an arg. Rails may think that oouuw this is my "label"(which is not). So you need to tell rails explicitly that this is my label and this is my template(in case of edit).However, because "new" just need a label you don't have to say this is my "@label"